# Create interdependent association model in rails - Best pratice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best practice for creating associated models for e.g. I would not want to save anything if one of the validation fails(say for C). Also, to show error for each model if any.

```
class A
 has_many :B
 has_many :C
end

class B
end

class C
end

class AController
  def create
    afields = params[:a_params]
    bfields = params[:b_params]
    cfields = params[:c_params]

    a = A.new(a_params)

    if a.save
      B.create(bfields)
      C.create(cfields)
      redirect_to a_index
    else
      redirect_to a_new_path
    end   

  end
end
```

Basically, I want to create a lot of interdependent models and want to save all of them or none if a single validation fails. I can do it some way or other but would like to know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord Validation's [`validates_associated`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated) method to serve your purpose:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :B
 has_many :C

 validates_associated :B, :C
end
```

#### Edit:

You could alternatively use, `validates_associated` in `B` and `C` models like this:

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :A

 validates_associated :A
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :A

 validates_associated :A
end
```

That way, it will ensure that associated `A` is present before creating `B`'s record or `C`'s record.

But be careful, you can't use `validates_associated` in both associations (`has_many` and `belongs_to`) as that will cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: could you please explain what you want exactly? elaborate the requirement a bit

Comment: when you have `validates_associated :B, :C` in your `A` model, then, `a.save` will fail if unless of of its associated B and C records are valid.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use rails [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), and use the bang! version of the save!/create!

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  A.create!(aparams)
  B.create!(bparams)
  C.create!(cparams)
end
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for something similar

Comment: You should probably add a rescue in there... that's the whole point of using the bang method of create.